# Is a balloon rocket launch pad possible?

Tags: internal-consistency, hard-science, atmosphere, rockets

Rockets consume a lot of fuel and carry not eough payload.
To reduce the fuel needed, why not send it in the mesosphere?

Imagine a big balloon, capable of carrying a small rocket to the mesosphere (or at least stratopause) where about 99.9% of the air is located under, so basically, its almost a vacuum.

We would drastically reduce air friction: the rocket would be smaller.

How big would the ballon need to be (we could reuse it)?

For 5 tons of payload, how much of liquid oxygen and liquid hydrogen would we need (as rocket fuel)? How about for 10 tons of payload?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Balloons just...float away you can't control their course. They make for excellent targets since they can't be stealth.

Comment: Shouldn’t this question be on the space exploration stack exchange?

Comment: Any question that asks about "real world stuff" is fair game here on WB.SE in an effort to understand how such things might be applied to a fictional world.

Comment: @elemtilas That is false. All other question requirements must till be met.

Comment: Most of the energy is expended in accelerating the vehicle and payload to orbital velocity. Only a small part is expended pushing the rocket out of the atmosphere. So the answer is, there would be a little saving on fuel, but nothing to write home about. Full explanation in [XKCD What-If #58](https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/).

Comment: This is the 'rocketoon' concept. There was some work in the 1950s. NASA, I think, has looked into its possibilities. The main upshot is that it is impracticable.

Comment: @Aify The best current understanding of the issue is that this response is at least provisionally correct: [according to here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161/a-proposal-to-finalize-the-are-real-world-questions-on-topic-debate)

Comment: @elemtilas and my response specifically is elaborated on in the second half of the main body of the post you linked. Thanks for proving my point. Additionally, the post specifically asks for community feedback; implying that your response is still wrong since the post is merely a **suggestion** until a decision is officially made. Based on the lack of a status-completed tag or accepted answer, the decision has obviously not yet been made.

Comment: @Aify Whether or not it is languishing on meta, it is still the best practice according to the community (a long string of answers, positive votes, discussion). It may not be the Rules, but it stands as the best statement of community decision to date. So, yes, questions about real world stuff are in fact welcome here, as that is how, and especially given some kind of worldbuilding context, we can understand how these kinds of things might function in a fictional setting. Enough said.

Comment: @elemtilas You've missed my point. I never said that "real world stuff" is off topic - I simply said that **ALL OTHER QUESTION REQUIREMENTS MUST STILL BE MET** in order for it to be on topic. You **MUST** include this caveat if you're going to claim your original statement of "Any question that asks about real world stuff is fair game".

Answer (score 5):

Achieving orbit is much more about velocity (gaining 16,000+ mph) than about altitude.

For vertical-launch rockets, a higher launch platform will save a few seconds' drag. The extra complexity is generally not worthwhile.

Horizontal-launch rockets (like [Pegasus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pegasus_(rocket))) spend longer in the atmosphere, so reducing atmospheric drag is worthwhile. Instead of a stationary launch site, they get a small extra velocity boost from their launch aircraft...since velocity is *still* more important than altitude if you want to make orbit. Note that no current horizontal-launch systems can handle 5 tons of payload.

Answer (score 0):

Using a balloon to launch a rocket is already a thing. Especially interesting here will be the democratization & commercialization of launching micro a/o nano satellites from a relatively cheaper platform.

[Article](http://www.iflscience.com/space/a-company-has-launched-a-rocket-from-a-balloon-for-the-first-time/)

Using a dirigible HAPS may also be a way to go, as you can control the platform's motions in the way you can't with a balloon. Plus the station can be manned & manoeuvred more easily.

[WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-altitude_platform_station)

The first such launch was 70 years ago:

[Rockoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockoon)

Answer (score -1):

You could have a rail system thousands of miles long, or a giant cannon, lifted miles high above at least part of the atmosphere by countless thousands of giant balloons, to accelerate a rocket to a good fraction of orbital velocity.  Then the rocket would have to provide the rest of the acceleration and also circularize the orbit at the right altitude.

Such a system would be very expensive and would probably need a very high volume of launches to be worthwhile.

Answer (score -2):

Such a balloon rocket launch pad would probably be a very worthwhile and cost-effective endeavor somewhere like Venus, with a far thicker and denser atmosphere and with extremely difficult surface conditions. On Earth, not so much.